# Do all-caps titles algorithmically work on YouTube?

Tags: youtube

All-caps titles or title words may look tempting or tantalizing, but do they really work to promote your videos? How does the YouTube algorithm handle all-caps titles?

Answer (score 1):

The Algorithm doesn't care about capitalization, it only cares about the words themselves.

That said, a part- or full-caps title and a flashy thumbnail may attract the viewer's attention more than a full-lowercase one — a video's success isn't solely dependent on The Algorithm, your ability to market yourself and, of course, to create good videos is a big part as well.

YouTube has a learning platform on how to grow one's channel: https://creatoracademy.youtube.com/